# How to update/upgrade a spring boot cloud application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I want to find out what is the best way to update a spring boot application in production without affecting clients that calls these microservices?

The spring boot application uses Consul for service registration.
So, stopping the spring boot app, would take down the service and clients would not be able to call this service until it starts up again and registers itself with Consul.

Is this just the way it is supposed to work, or is there a workaround to reduce downtime to 0? For e.x. start up the updated version of the spring boot app (in this case there would be 2 servers registered under Consul, 1 old version, 1 new version), then kill the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Production systems typically employ **Rolling Updates** strategy to incrementally upgrade/downgrade the services to achieve ZDD (Zero Downtime Deployments).

Orchestration frameworks (like Kubernetes) has this feature in-built:

[Rolling Updates in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/)